# Faces missing when opening model in UE4

Tags: rendering, normals, faces

When I transfer my character over to UE4 my character does not look quite right.. the wings are off and faces seem missing.

[image: Image of Character in UE4]

Comment: Check the normals of those faces, seems like they are inverted.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Related: ttp://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/how-to-make-all-faces-flip-to-the-right-consistent-direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing ctrl+N allowed blender to re-do the face normals, arranging inverted to standard and fixing bad "inverted/missing" faces.